# How do I proof or disprove that the size of a document influences classification accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, python

I have a multinomial Naive Bayes model that classifies a document into 1 of 178 classes. This goes well about 50% of the time, so it's pretty good (for my use case) considering the large set of classes. Now, I want to know if by knowing the size of the input document (in bytes) I can say anything about the confidence of the prediction. Intuitively I would say, smaller documents hold less information about its class and thus will generally result in worse predictions.

Assume a pandas dataframe with the following data: "actual", "predicted", "size". Is it possible to statistically prove if the size document has any influence over a correct or incorrect prediction?

Extra information:
There are about 8000 records
There is no clear grouping of document sizes, (in the 8000 records, there are about 5000 different document sizes)

I have tried using logistic regression with MLE and OLS, but I am unsure if this is scientifically correct.

Logistic recression MLE implementation:
I separated my data into correct and incorrect predictions, but this doesn't seem fair, since a correct prediction is inherently much less likely then an incorrect prediction. Furthermore, I read somewhere this assumes a normal distribution of the size variable, but it is not normally distributed.

```py
# Add an intercept term
data_no_outliers['intercept'] = 1

# Fit logistic regression model
logit_model_no_outliers = sm.Logit(data_no_outliers['correct'], data_no_outliers[['intercept', size_column]])
result = logit_model_no_outliers.fit()

----------------------------------------
results:

Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.691922
         Iterations 3
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                correct   No. Observations:                 8532
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                     8530
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Fri, 17 Nov 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:               2.621e-06
Time:                        13:46:38   Log-Likelihood:                -5903.5
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -5903.5
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                    0.8604
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intercept      0.1030      0.031      3.290      0.001       0.042       0.164
size          -0.0008      0.005     -0.176      0.860      -0.010       0.009
==============================================================================
```

OLS implementation:
I am pretty sure this is incorrect, since it doesn't even use the actual data.

````py
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
results['prediction_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(results['prediction'])

# Assuming df is your DataFrame
X = sm.add_constant(results['size'])  # Add a constant term
y = results['prediction_encoded']

# Fit a non-parametric regression model
smModel = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

--------------------------------
results:

OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:     prediction_encoded   R-squared:                       0.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.6955
Date:                Fri, 17 Nov 2023   Prob (F-statistic):              0.404
Time:                        15:09:45   Log-Likelihood:                -42579.
No. Observations:                8591   AIC:                         8.516e+04
Df Residuals:                    8589   BIC:                         8.518e+04
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         51.8788      0.415    124.995      0.000      51.065      52.692
size           0.0298      0.036      0.834      0.404      -0.040       0.100
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                     1001.822   Durbin-Watson:                   1.038
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              444.613
Skew:                           0.375   Prob(JB):                     2.84e-97
Kurtosis:                       2.177   Cond. No.                         13.0
==============================================================================
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What was your outcome variable in the logistic regression? The binary correct/incorrect of the classifications? $//$ How did you use OLS in the logistic regression?

Comment: @Dave I have edited my question with the information you asked.